# Windows 10 restarts suddenly without any prompt - lpksetup

Tags: windows-10, reboot

Please help understand why this happens.

Does Microsoft still practice the habit of restarting the computer without user's consent? Do they simply cannot understand such simple common sense that you must ask the user when to restart still?

Is there a way to stop this from happing again? Not only my work has gone, it also created state discrepancy e.g. VM states which I need to fix.

[image]

- [How to find out why your PC shut down for no reason on Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-find-reason-pc-shutdown-no-reason-windows-10)

Answer (score 1):

Note that the changes involving the language pack were made "12/11/2021", perhaps during Windows Update, at which time you should have seen a notice that the system would be restarted [**when not in active use**](https://www.howtogeek.com/264325/how-to-set-active-hours-so-windows-10-wont-restart-at-a-bad-time/). The restart was not performed until "12/31/2021", *20 days later*.

Was the restart message ignored or forgotten? Was it never seen, because of the manner in which update was performed (e.g., in a corporate environment)?

If this is your own PC, and you have some pressing reason to perform the beginning of an update, and not complete it through rebooting, you can [defer automatic restarts indefinitely](https://www.minitool.com/news/win10-stop-automatic-restart-during-active-hours.html) at the risk of having updates incompletely installed, should one forget to restart.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have set active hours in the windows update page. So if you were not active during that time usually computer restart it selves.

[image]